# onreadystagechange only called once (socket and ajax)

Tags: ajax, sockets

I am experimenting ajax with socket. I found that my server program could receive data sent from client and the xml file received was correct. However, the onreadystage callback function was only called once (when readyState=1). Am I doing anything wrong?
Here are my functions related to ajax:

```
function requestAjax(){
        var msg=document.getElementById("msgToSocket").value;           
        var xhr=false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
        }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
            xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if(xhr){
            xhr.open("GET", "socketSample1Ajax.php?msg="+msg+"&count="+(++ajaxCount), true);
            xhr.onreadystagechange=sendMsgToAjax(xhr);
            xhr.send(null);
        }

    }

function sendMsgToAjax(xhr){
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            var xmlDoc=xhr.responseXML;
            var read=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("read")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var write=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("write")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("readParagraph").innerHTML=read;
            document.getElementById("writeParagraph").innerHTML=write;
        }
    }
```

and my ajax serving as client of socket:

```
if(isset($_GET["msg"])){
    $msg=$_GET["msg"];
    if(!socket_write($socket, $msg))
        $resultWrite="Write failed";
    else
        $resultWrite="Written";
}
else{
    socket_write($socket, "No data input");
    $resultWrite="No data written";
}
$buffer=socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ)or die(socket_last_error($socket)."\n");
if(!$buffer)
    $resultRead="No data";
else
    $resultRead="Buffer Data: ".$buffer;
socket_close($socket);
```

Thank you for your help!